# Tkinter Label() display progressively slows down during a loop using update()

Tags: python, tkinter

My goal is to activate a loop with a button press and have the index (count) displayed in a box as it increases.  The loop should have the same execution time (for a given count) regardless of how many times the button is pressed.

The following "do_the_loop()" function does that nicely -- with one problem:  The loop slows down progressively as the absolute count gets larger (after one button press and continues through more than one button press).  The time it takes for the function to execute more-or-less doubles with each execution (button press).  I have timed the "Label(...).place(...)" and the "update()" parts of the loop to determine the source of the slowdown, and it seems to be in "update()" .  HOWEVER, by moving the "update()" function out of the "while" loop, roughly the same slowdowns occur even though "update()" is only executed once per run instead of 1000 times. (Try it: comment out "root.update()" in the "while" loop, and un-comment it above "count = 1").  Under these conditions, the "while" loop executes in about one third of a second consistently.  Consequently, the problem doesn't seem to be "update()" per se.  There seems to be a gremlin hiding in there someplace, and I'm missing it.

I would appreciate any light that anyone can shine on this issue.  I'm using Python 3.7.1 and Windows 10.  Thanks.

```
    from tkinter import *
    import time

    root = Tk()

    root.title("Slowdown Problem")
    root.geometry("300x250+1335+0")
    root.configure(background="lightgray")

    def do_the_loop():
        # Erases the count when button is pressed
        canvas = Canvas(root, height= 30, width=60, bg="powderblue")
        canvas.place(x=115, y=145)

        #root.update()     

        count = 1
        total_count = 1000

        start = time.perf_counter()

        while count <= total_count:                
            Label(root, height=1, width=5, anchor=E, background="powderblue",  
                  text=str(count),
                  fg="red", font=("Arial Black", 10)).place(x=120, y=150)

            root.update()    # Update the display with each count

            count += 1

        print("Count:", count, "  Loop time:", str(time.perf_counter() - start))

    #======================== CREATE GO BUTTON ==============================
    Button(root, text="  GO  ", font=("Arial Black", 20), bd=7, command=do_the_loop,
       bg="light green", height=2, width=7).place(x=70, y=20)    

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: At a guess its because you are adding more `Label` elements to the ui on each click. They are on top of each other so you dont notice the duplications. The update then has to progressively draw more elements each time and so is slower. Instead use one label and update it using a StringVar or IntVar.

Comment: Right on!  That fixed the problem.  Pays to know what your code is doing, doesn't it.  LOL  Thanks, Paul!  I appreciate your help.